# Stacked Notifications Extra Click

Tags: wear-os

I'm developing a simple application, and my goal is to get stacked notifications working on the Android Wear watch, according to this webpage: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

When there exist multiple stacked notifications, you have to click on the stack before you can swipe to the left to get access to any extra actions (e.g., a voice reply action). However, when there is only *one* stacked notification, I still have to click on the "stack" to get access to the extra actions. This is a very annoying and unintuitive extra click to have to do as a user, and I'm thinking I'm probably doing something wrong. Does anyone have any experience with this issue, and if so, what did you to do work around it? The code I'm using is essentially identical to the code found in the link above, except I'm only issuing one stacked notification on the watch along with the summary notification on the phone.

Comment: I have this issue too. Also the action isn't related to the 'visible' card, just the first one which seems to make this extra click pointless as you can't make an action per card :-/